# How to configure vi in Ubuntu

Tags: configuration, vi

I am using `vi` with

```
set ts=4
set number
```

configuration and I am tired of settings these each time I open the `vi` editor on command line. So I want to configure `vi` with a configuration file that I can embed the settings listed above however, I could not find the config file for `vi` in Ubuntu. What is the exact location of `vi` config file in Ubuntu or which way I can configure `vi`? Any ideas ?

Note: This question is only specific to `vi`, not `vim`.

Comment: I do not understand why this question earned a down vote? Question is not clear, not eligible, bad formatting, wonder exactly what is the reason so that I can change it to a better form? It's bad to see getting down vote with no comments, not any negative feedback within a comment.

Comment: let me ask you this: when you say `vi` do you mean that you installed a different implementation of vi other than what came by default ?

Comment: On Ubuntu, `vi` is some version of Vim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open a new file in your home directory called `.exrc`, and put your configurations therein.